# How to extract data from multiple closed excel workbooks for placing in a separate workbook in different worksheets through VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

(Beginner VBA coder here!)
Does anyone know how to extract multiple, specific cell data from multiple closed workbooks that have the same worksheet format?

I am currently tasked to copy very specific data from certain cells from many different and new (but same format) sources and transfer them into another group of specific cells in an existing masterlist with different worksheets.

This is the code I wished would help, but it is lacking in too many ways as compared to what I need...

```
Sub Importsheet() 
Dim Importsheet As Worksheet 
'import worksheet from a closed workbook
Sheets.Add Type:= _ 
'e.g. directory below
"C:\Users\Loli\Desktop\Testing1.xlsx" 
End Sub
```

This code helps me get the ***sheets*** out of the closed source workbook but not the specifically placed cells in the closed source excel. It also can't paste the data in specifically placed cells in different sheets in the destination excel.

Comment: Why not loop through the import and add the data to a new sheet called Temp then extract the specific cells from there and add them to your master, then delete the Temp Sheet and loop through to the next file?

Comment: Do you have a list of all the files to be imported? or are they grouped in the same folder (directory)?

Comment: To copy specific cells you will need to open the Excel file (this can be hidden in the background and read only, there are several tutorials for this on google) and then do a copy and paste where ever you want to. But without opening the source Excel file I see barely a chance to solve this.

Comment: @Xabier Thanks for the response! The workbooks are always grouped together in the same windows folder. I understand your idea but I would still wish to make the system simpler to use as the files I import usually >40 and is refreshed daily.

Comment: Peh's comments are the way to go, you can loop through all .xlsx files in the folder and then let the code update your master, then maybe remove the files from that folder so that they aren't imported a second time around...

Comment: The workbooks you are trying to import, do they all have a worksheet with the same name?

Comment: @Xabier Unfortunately, the excel file's do not have the same name, they are all based on a range of dates. E.g. "Filename"&"010117 - 020217"

Comment: I mean, not the workbooks, but the worksheets in each workbook?

Comment: @Xabier the worksheets are also not named in the same format. Sorry, I read wrongly.

Comment: @GLY, I'm trying to formulate an answer, but I just don't have enough information, is it always the first sheet in each workbook that you are interested in? what is the range that you want to copy, is that range always the same in every workbook/worksheet?

Comment: @Xabier The sheets are also not always from the first sheet and the range varies. I'll go into greater detail here... Firstly, let's say I have 6 workbooks and 1 master. (WB1, WB2, WB3...+ Master WB) In WB1, I would have to extract Cells A1:S11 from the a sheet and the sheet is named based on the day itself. The data then needs to be pasted on the master WB at a specific cell range,sheet1 (e.g. Cell b1:s11). On WB2 i would have to copy only from one cell, say d29 and paste it on cell f16 on the 2nd sheet on the master WB

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to completely understand your requirements as it seems like sometimes you want to copy a range and some other times a single cell, so to point you in the right direction my answer only shows how to open and copy the relevant Sheet into your master workbook to then be able to reference the cell/ranges you want

(I would once you get your data then delete the Worksheet, so that your master doesn't suddenly becomes massive in size):

```
Sub ImportSheet() 
    Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String 
    Dim sThisBk As Workbook 
    Dim vfilename As Variant 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook 
    sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _ 
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook")  'open dialog to choose the file you want, you can change this to loop through a folder if they are all in there.
    If sImportFile = "False" Then 'check if a file was selected before importing
        MsgBox "No File Selected!" 
        Exit Sub 

    Else 
        vfilename = Split(sImportFile, "\") 
        sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename)) 
        Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sImportFile 'open the selected file

        Set wbBk = Workbooks(sFile) 
        With wbBk 
            If SheetExists("Raw_Data") Then ' you should change this to the date, you can do this easily by using a variable such as if SheetExists(variableDate) then, where variableDate = "12/12/2017" or something similar
                Set wsSht = .Sheets("Raw_Data") 
                wsSht.Copy before:=sThisBk.Sheets("Sheet1") 'copy the worksheet into your master
                'WsSht.range("A1:B2").copy Destination:=sThisBk.Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").paste xlpastevalues 'use this to copy a specified range in this case A1:B2 to a sheet in master workbook called Temp A1
            Else 
                MsgBox "There is no sheet with name :Raw_Data in:" & vbCr & .Name 
            End If 
            wbBk.Close SaveChanges:=False 
        End With 
    End If 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub 

Private Function SheetExists(sWSName As String) As Boolean 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName) 
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True 
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! By any chance, do you know of any code that can extract only a range of data from a closed excel instead of the entire sheet?

Comment: I've added a line of code to my answer to copy the specified range of the worksheet to be copied.. Please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped you, thanks.